# Why are functions globally accessable in Perl

Tags: perl, function

I have just started reading about Perl. I know it is too early to ask a question (I should continue reading) but I cannot help myself.

I am a c++ developer. What I noticed in Perl is that functions are "global". You don't need to "include" anything to use a lot of functions. In c++, for example, if you want to use a `string`, you have to include `string` from stl. In perl, you don't have to include anything to manipulate strings or numbers (math functions). So, my question is:

Why should one make everything "public"? If I want to manipulate strings, why do I need access to math functions?

Comment: Because Perl is not C++? Different languages provide different features out of the box.

Comment: You're also dealing with the difference between a compiled language versus an interpreted language.  In a compiled language, you definitely want to selectively #include functionality in your program, because it's going to be added to the bin.  Perl as an interpreted language on the other hand includes many core libraries out of the box.  But it also has its add-ons via cpan or whatever other source.

Comment: @Miller, Saying "languages requiring a common runtime library for all programs" would be more accurate and avoid the confusion that stems from Perl being a compiled language too. It has nothing to do with compiled or interpreted, whatever those mean.

Comment: You will sure get an real answer from smater developers as me, but try think about it in a form: the perl functions are like "keywords". For example: the `defined` "keyword" is a function too. The `map { }...` is a function. And because it is a intepreter, it doesn't matter. Anyway, you will lean than in the perl exists like `#include` in a form "use Module;". Perl has __EXCELLENT__ documentation (the best what i ever saw in for programming languages). For the functions, check: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html

Comment: Why do you see it as a problem to have access to math functions when you want to manipulate strings?  Are you imagining that there's some sort of performance penalty?

Comment: @AndyLester performance or maybe memory usage (though as other's answered, it is interpreted)

Comment: Perl, unlike C++, has a large number of *predefined* functions whose names are effectively (almost) keywords. Perl's `substr()`, for example, is built into the language in much the same way that C++'s `+` is. Perl also supports user-defined functions which can be organized into modules; those can be made available with a `use` directive. It happens that predefined, user-defined, and module-defined functions can be called with the same syntax.

Comment: @KeithThompson you should write your comment as answer...;)

Comment: @KeithThompson Thank you, I got it. Please, write an answer, so I can accept

Comment: Why the votes to close? It's a good question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl, unlike C++, has a large number of predefined functions whose names are effectively (almost) keywords. (According to ikegami's comment above, they're keywords but not reserved words.)

Perl's `substr()`, for example, is built into the language in much the same way that C++'s `+` is.

Historically, the reason for this is *convenience*. It's very common to write 1-line Perl scripts that can do moderately complex things, because you don't need several lines of `#include` directives to enable common functionality. You also don't need to define a "main" function/subroutine; execution simply begins at the top of your script:

```
$ perl -e 'print scalar localtime time, "\n"'
Wed Mar 26 13:30:04 2014
```

Perl also supports user-defined functions which can be organized into modules; those can be made available with a `use` directive.

It happens that predefined, user-defined, and module-defined functions can be called with the same syntax.

An example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday);

my $now = time();                   # time is a built-in function
my ($sec, $usec) = gettimeofday();  # gettimeofday() is defined in Time::HiRes
my $then = yesterday();             # yesterday() is defined below

print  "Yesterday:      $then\n";
print  "Now:            $now\n";
printf "More precisely: %d.%06d\n", $sec, $usec;

sub yesterday {
    return time() - 86400;
}
```

Comment: e.g. `perl -E"sub length { 4 }  say length 'abc';"` Not reserved words since this compiles. Keywords because this doesn't print 4.

Comment: Ok, technically, they're keywords if the parser knows about them, and the above doesn't actually demonstrate that. But given that they're operators, the parser must know about them. Even without looking at the source, that guarantees that they're keywords if not reserved words.

Answer (score 7):

I believe Perl was originally intended to be an admin's tool, and thus it was provided with an extensive list of [operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html) to that end. Some of them even give access to databases!

While these are referred to as functions in the Perl world (based on the name of the file in which they are documented), they aren't functions in the C++ sense of the word<sup>[1]</sup>. They are really operators<sup>[2]</sup>, just like `not` and `and`. As operators, they aren't constrained to normal subroutine syntax. For example, `print` and `system`'s syntax cannot be replicated by subroutines, a second reason for these to be builtin.

Admittedly, if Perl was written today, things would be different. The field of computer science has continually been inventing new ways of limiting scope. We place more emphasis on encapsulation and on minimal cores now. Most of the operators would be written as subroutines in modules, and most of the operators with abnormal syntax would be designed to take normal subroutine arguments. This is not speculative; you only need to take a look at Perl6, and I'll bet you'll find this is true. So why should one make everything public? We shouldn't.

---

1. "Subroutine" is the Perl word for what C++ calls a function.
2. The first two sentences of perlfunc are: "The functions in this section can serve as terms in an expression. They fall into two major categories: list operators and named unary operators."

   Most of them end up being compiled to an identically-named operator in the Perl virtual machine.

   ```
   >perl -MO=Concise,-exec -E"sub f { 'abcdef' }  say(substr(f(), 2, 3));"
   1  <0> enter
   2  <;> nextstate(main 48 -e:1) v:%,{,469764096
   3  <0> pushmark s
   4  <0> pushmark s
   5  <#> gv[*f] s
   6  <1> entersub[t3] sKS/TARG   <- A subroutine call
   7  <$> const[IV 2] s
   8  <$> const[IV 3] s
   9  <@> substr[t4] sK/3         <- substr operator
   a  <@> say vK                  <- say operator
   b  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
   -e syntax OK
   ```

Comment: I don't feel that Keith actually answers your question. You asked why Perl does it that way, and he simply explained what Perl does, all of which C++ could also do. I'm posting this answer to address that [and because I actually stated writing it before he posted his, so no use letting it go to waste! :)]